# When reading a text file, how to get rid of "\n" when extracted in python

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I am writing a program where you have to extract bits of text from a text file. The specific bit of text is the save directory where I would like to save the files produced by my program. Here is my code:

```
    file = open("datafile.txt", "r")
    SaveDir = file.read()
    print SaveDir
```

That seems to be working properly, the output is exactly as it should be, "/home/marc/QuickJotProgram/QuickJotTexts
"

Please note that the program skips a line before the end quote which is my problem

It's not a problem until later in the program where I use the SaveDir variable:

```
text_file = open(os.path.join(SaveDir, title), "w")
```

The error message is:

```
text_file = open(os.path.join(SaveDir, title), "w")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:      '/home/marc/QuickJotProgram/QuickJotTexts\n/file'
```

The only thing that should not be there is the "\n" I just need to get rid of that, and the program will run smoothly.

Thanks ubuntu :)

Comment: sorry for posting a google search but this has been answered so many times it would be a pity to be answered again... https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=python%20remove%20newline

Comment: if you call the dupe card only duplicates on askubuntu matter @hakermania  ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on StackOverFlow?

Comment: @Yousef's so they close it as duplicated? nah, it should just get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing \n from a string:

```
newString = oldString.replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even easier (and better):

```
new_str = old_str.rstrip()
```

This strips all whitespace on the right.